# Showing Interstitial ad in webView app for several time

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I Am Using Following Code to Show Admob Industrial Ad and Banner Ad in a WebView App. Banner AD Works Properly But Interstitial AD Shows Ad for One Time. But I Want to Show AD Every Time  When a Webpage Is Load. Please suggest me code.

```
package com.catutorial.vatbd;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));



    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://tax.catutorial.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.catutorial.vatbd.MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}




/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "VAT and Tax rate of Bangladesh");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Visit catutorial.com for CA suggestion");
    return intent;
}


public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
}
```